# ASP Issue: Is it possible to pass session variables as parameters to functions in the Global.asa file?

Tags: session, variables, asp-classic, global.asa

I plan to write the Global.asa file in JavaScript. When a session or application ends, I need changes to be made in a database. Specifically, I need to break up a string and use it in a query in the Global.asa functions. That part doesn't puzzle me at all. Just the part about passing a session variable in as a parameter. I imagine my Global.asa to look something like this:

(Let's say the two variables "variable1" and "variable2" were session variables)

```
<script language="JScript" runat="Server">
function Application_OnStart() {
}

function Application_OnEnd(variable1) {
}

function Session_OnStart() {
}

function Session_OnEnd(variable2) {
}
</script>
```

So, I'm not sure if what I'm asking is even feasible. If so, any tips? Keep in mind that I am working in ASP, not ASP.NET. Also, I'm a bit new to using server-side code, so pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you suggest is not feasible.

The functions in the global.asa file are callbacks for events. The functions *get* called, all with no parameters.

You can make use of the [`Session`](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_session.asp) object to do what you want.

In your code you can set a session variable like this:

```
session("userid") = 856
```

In your global.asa you can then use:

```
variable1 = session("userid")
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using VBScript for your Global.asa? I've never coded a Global.asa in javascript, but you *could* code it in VB and use Session or Application level variables:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=VBScript RUNAT=Server>

Sub Application_OnStart()
    'initialize application level variables
    Application("ConnectionString") = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" & Server.mappath("access_db/mydb.mdb")
End Sub

Sub Application_OnEnd()
    Application("ConnectionString") = ""
End Sub

Sub Session_OnStart()
    'initialize session level variables
    Session("UserIP") = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
End Sub

Sub Session_OnEnd()
    Session("UserIP") = ""
End Sub
```

Not sure if you can pass a variable into the predefined functions as such, but you can use Session or Application variables anywhere on the website, including within these functions.

Comment: You can use all available scripting languages in the global.asa file. This includes JScript. You cannot pass variables to these functions.